# gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors not installing

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1. I'm trying to install the Elegance Colors theme using the instructions here: https://github.com/numixproject/elegance-colors

However, I'm not able to install it as the "package cannot be located". I wrote the same exact statements into the terminal as shown in the link but it is still not working. Here is the output I get in the terminal:

```
anurag@Anurag-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:satyajit-happy/themes
[sudo] password for anurag: 
This PPA contains various themes for Gnome and Xfce.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~satyajit-happy/+archive/ubuntu/themes
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpbb1ar3tg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpbb1ar3tg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 5F0D930C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpbb1ar3tg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 5F0D930C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Satyajit Sahoo" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
anurag@Anurag-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]                                                             
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]                                                                         
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                           
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial InRelease                               
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                 
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial Release
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [328 kB]
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [323 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [300 kB]
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [297 kB]
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 1,439 kB in 5s (287 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
anurag@Anurag-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors
```

I'm not able to figure out what the cause could be and how to fix it. I really like this theme and want it. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: That PPA does not contain packages for Ubuntu 16.04.  See it [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu/dists/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the PPA you added does not serve your Ubuntu version (16.04, Xenial). This is, there is no packages available for it. As you can see from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu/dists/) the PPA only has packages for 15.10 and earlier.

To be able to install the package, go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and open the file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/satyajit-happy-themes-xenial.list`. Inside, you will see the following:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu xenial main
```

Change the `xenial` word with `wily`. Save, and run `sudo apt-get update` again.

Now your machine will connect to the Wily repository of that package, found [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/), and will give you the latest package available of the application you want.